# Pretty Json from pyparsing

Tags: python, pyparsing

So, i have some expressions in EBNF form for parsing some systems of differential equations

```
END = Literal(';').suppress()
POINT = Literal('.')
COMMA = Literal(',').suppress()
COLON = Word(':', max=1).suppress()
EQUAL = Literal('=').suppress()
VARNAME = Word(alphas, max=1)
NATNUM = Word(nums)  # 1234567890
SIGN = oneOf('+ -')
OPER = oneOf('+ - * / ^ ')
REALNUM = Combine(Optional(SIGN) + NATNUM + Optional(POINT + NATNUM))  # Real Numbers 2.3, 4.5
STEP = Dict(Group('Step' + COLON + REALNUM + END))  # Step: 0.01 ;
RANGE = Dict(Group('Range' + COLON + REALNUM + END))  # Range: 2.0 ;
VARINIT = Group(VARNAME + Suppress('=') + REALNUM)  # x=32.31
ZEROVAR = Dict(Group('Vars0' + COLON + VARINIT + Optional(COMMA + VARINIT) + END))
COEFF = Dict(Group('Coeff' + COLON + VARINIT + Optional(COMMA + VARINIT) + END))
EXPESS = Forward()
EXPESS << Combine((REALNUM | VARNAME) + ZeroOrMore(OPER + EXPESS), adjacent=False)
IDENT = Combine('d'+VARNAME)
FUNC = Group(IDENT + EQUAL + EXPESS)
DIFUR = Dict(Group('Exp' + COLON + FUNC + ZeroOrMore(COMMA + FUNC) + END))
STATE = Suppress("Start") + DIFUR + ZEROVAR + COEFF + STEP + RANGE + Suppress("Stop")
```

I'd like to receive such kind of JSON by parsing the finally STATE expression:

```
{
'Vars0': {
            'y', '0.55',
            'x', '0.02',
            },
'Exp': {
        'dx': 'a*x-y',
        'dy': 'b*x-y',
        'dz':'800-2*4*x+z'
        },
'Range': '2.0',
'Step': '0.05', 
'Coeff': {
            'a': '5',
            'b': '2'
        }
}
```

But instead i've got some thing ugly like this for example 'Vars0': ([(['y', '0.55'], {}), (['x', '0.02'], {})], {})  and etc.
What is my stupid mistake?
p.s. parsing plain text for parsing can be like [this](https://pastebin.com/VfL8cy4k)

Comment: parseString returns a ParseResults object, whose repr looks like what you posted. You didn't post the code that actually calls parseString, but assuming it was something like `result = expr.parseString(input_source); print(result)`, try `print(result.dump())` instead. More info on the ParseResults API can be found at the oniine docs: https://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/pyparsing.ParseResults-class.html

Comment: If you want JSON, probably best would be `json.dumps(result.asDict())`, assuming you have named all the fields that you want included in the JSON output. Depending on how you have used pyparsing Groups, you may need to deref by one leve and do `json.dumps(result[0].asDict())`.

Answer (score 1):

What you have isn't JSON, it's a Python dictionary variable, which fortunately means it can be pretty printed with the `pprint` module.

Have a look, specifically, at `pprint.pprint`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint .

Setting an indent of 4 and a width of 1 might produce something pleasing to you. Example: https://ideone.com/pYESaW

Comment: Not quite - pyparsing's parsed results are returned as a `ParseResults` object. Since this object supports both list and dict access modes, it's repr can be ugly-looking - better to use `print(results.dump())`.  If there are no named results, then even easier is to do `results.pprint()`, which internally calls `pprint.pprint`.

Comment: Ah, that's worth knowing! That's my mistake, from trying to adapt my use of other parsers where I'd typically build and return dicts rather than a libraries own `ParseResults` class. Thanks, and it's certainly worth knowing about the classes own reference to `pprint`!

Comment: Yes, I finally just got tired of doing `import pprint; pprint.pprint(results.asList())` and just made it part of the API. `ParseResults.pprint` accepts all the keyword args you would pass to `pprint.pprint` and forwards them on in its own internal call.

Comment: Answers that don't stand on their own are discouraged because the link can break in the future. Incorporate your ideone link content into the answer.